# Обособление «в теории»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводная-конструкция

`В теории(,) и это возможно.`

Нужна ли запятая после *в теории*? Является ли это вообще вводным словосочетанием?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смысл предложений **разный**:

(1) ***В теории** и это возмОжно.*

Речь идет о теории какого-либо вопроса. Тема: теория и практика.

(2) **В теОрии,** //  и это возмОжно.

Здесь скорее разговорный оценочный вариант со значением "в принципе". Он может касаться любой темы разговора.

Это **авторская** пунктуация, обозначение паузы. Но запятая нужна, чтобы различить варианты.

.

Comment: Это скорее не _в принципе_, а _по сути_ в разговорном. То есть если это разговорный, то запятая нужна, а если имеется в виду _теоретически_, то нет?

Comment: Максим, чуть позже отвечу, сейчас времени мало.

Comment: Ну что, время появилось? Можете пояснить, верны ли мои суждения?

Comment: Нет, не появилось. Ухожу!  На ваш вопрос коротко не ответишь.

Comment: В конце концов в этом и суть: галочки зарабатывать нужно, их просто так не дадут. Но, в принципе, принимаю ответ, я разобрался в нем.

Comment: Я придумала синоним для вас: в теории –  это если смотреть на любую проблему умозрительно.  Разговорная речь оформляется в соответствии с тремя принципами пунктуации, как и книжная. Но там особый синтаксис, свои синтаксические и интонационные особенности.